# views pager by ajax

Tags: views, ajax, paging

I have multiple views in a page. Each of the views has its own pager. When I go to page 2 of one of the views `"?page=1"` appears at the end of the URL but I do not want it.

How can I load whole of the views by AJAX so that after paging the URL does not change?
I've tested [this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2401677) but the problem is not solved.

Comment: Turn on AJAX in the view?

Comment: @Kevin yes AJAX is enabled